# Quando da erro 404 no header, e redirecionar para uma pagina especifica?

Tags: php, http, redirecionamento

Tenho essa pagina com link OFF: https://uploadbr.com/1j1w

Porem não adianta eu fazer isso com `.htaccess`, porque eu ja tentei e não vai, quero fazer com `php`.

Tentei algo como isso:

```html
if($httpCode == 404) {
    /* REDIRECT AQUI */
}
```

Mas não funcionou, como faço isso ?

Comment: Esse site é seu, ou você obtém informações dele e quer verificar se o mesmo está off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tentou da seguinte forma no .htaccess?

**ErrorDocument 404 /pagina-a-mostrar.php**

Se não funcionar, essa forma que você está tentando fazer com **if** seria assim: https://pastebin.com/QLVTG4EP